ArcGIS single band raster: how to calculate number of clusters of one type
I have many single band rasters (.tif), with one per year for each site of interest. These show land use classes at 10m resolution, with values ranging 0-9.
For each raster, I want to calculate the number of clusters of one particular cell type (e.g. type 3). i.e. how many continuous / connected clusters of one land use type are there. Ideally I'd like to specify a threshold for being considered separate clusters - e.g. at least 50m (5 cells) to be considered 2 clusters of type 3.
Ideally I'd also like to know what % of the raster area these clusters cover.
I have looked at a lot of tools but can't seem to find one that would allow me to find this value.
